# Trying to align a paragrap and heading

Tags: css

i have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs/web/frontend.php/miembros/show/id/1).

login: fer
password: m
Note: after login you will be redirected to another page. Then click again the link i mention.

As you can see the sentence "Editar mi perfil" is not aligned with the baseline of "Fernando Salgado...". I tried with vertical-align but it doesn't work..

Any help ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution: move the `<a>` element inside the `<h2>` element and style accordingly. Otherwise you're in for some hacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the ability to move elements around (as suggested by Tatu earlier), you could add something like `margin-top: 4px;` to the `#cabecera_derecha` style.